# Setting up VNC on headless Mac Mini server

Tags: vnc, jenkins

I am trying to do Android UI testing with jenkins using a headless mac mini server as my build agent. From what I have gathered the easiest way to do this is to use the Xvnc plugin, however in order for the plugin to run a vncserver must be set up on the mac mini. What is the easiest way to set up vnc on a headless mac mini server? I am new to VNC so any insight would greatly help.

Comment: You'll have to attach a monitor and keyboard to do it, but once a VNC server is setup you can detach them and connect over the network.  Any  MacOSX compatible VNC server software should work for you, check Google.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a StackOverflow answer, but since this question was moved here, I'll have to answer here.

> From what I have gathered the easiest way to do this is to use the Xvnc plugin

This is wrong. The easiest way to run an Android emulator on a headless build machine is to run it with the `-no-window` option, so that it doesn't require a graphical environment.

If you use the [Android Emulator Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Android+Emulator+Plugin) for Jenkins to start your emulators for you, just untick the "Show emulator window" configuration option in your job configuration.

Comment: This was the first solution I tried. I have the emulator running with the "Show emulator window" unchecked and I have verified that the "-no-window" option is running, however the UI tests are still failing. I have double checked and the UI tests all pass when run on an actual android device so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

Comment: I've tried with the -no-window option, but certain UI tests will still fail even with it - specifically with the error  `FAILED java.lang.SecurityException: Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission`. See the bug filed [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175607). I'm going to try the VNC approach now.

(Late reply, I know, but this question comes up high in the list of results when googling for headless Android emulator setup.)